# Need Visualforce input field to update a different field on SalesForce object

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a visualforce page where a user inputs serial numbers for an asset (New_Asset_Install_LOC_Serial_Number__c), I need this serial number input field to update the main serial number field on the asset Object (SerialNumber). Currently the New_Asset_Install_LOC_Serial_Number__c field is being updated on the asset, but I also need this value to populate the SerialNumber field on the asset.

Here is my visualforce code:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" standardController="Case" extensions="installTicketUpdateAssetClass" id="thePage">
<apex:form id="theForm"> 
    <apex:pageblock id="Assets">

        <apex:pageBlockSection id="pbs" columns="1"> <!-- to allow the apex:input to show the label -->
            
            <apex:pageBlockTable rows="1" id="pbt3" value="{!Case.Assets__r}" var="asset">
            
                <apex:column style="width:12%;" headerValue="Product Code"><!-- to take the label dynamically -->
                     <apex:inputText style="width:80%;" disabled="true" styleClass="setupModelForId" value="{!asset.Product_Code_for_Paperless_Install_Docs__c}"  />
                </apex:column>
                
                <apex:column style="width:11%;" headerValue="ID Number"><!-- to take the label dynamically -->
                    <apex:inputText required="true" style="width:80%;" styleClass="idNumber" value="{!asset.New_Asset_Install_LOC_ID_Number__c}"  />
                </apex:column>
                
                <apex:column style="width:10%;" headerValue="B/W Starting Meter"><!-- to take the label dynamically -->
                    <apex:inputText required="true" styleClass="bwMeter" style="width:80%;" value="{!asset.New_Asset_Install_B_W_Meter__c}"  />
                </apex:column>
            
                <apex:column style="width:10%;" headerValue="Color Starting Meter"><!-- to take the label dynamically -->
                    <apex:inputText styleClass="colorMeter" style="width:80%;" value="{!asset.New_Asset_Install_Color_Meter__c}"  />
                </apex:column>
            
            <apex:column style="width:10%;" headerValue="I.P. Address"><!-- to take the label dynamically -->
                    <apex:inputText styleClass="ipAddress" style="width:90%;" value="{!asset.New_Asset_Install_Equipment_IP_Address__c}"  />
                </apex:column>
                
                <apex:column style="width:.01%;" headerValue=""><!-- to take the label dynamically -->
                    <apex:inputText disabled="true" style="width:.01%;" styleClass="setupIdNumber" value="{!asset.New_Asset_Setup_LOC_ID__c}"  />
                </apex:column>
            
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
            
            <apex:pageBlockTable id="pbt" value="{!Case.Assets__r}" var="asset">
                             
                <apex:column style="width:12%;" headerValue="Product Code"><!-- to take the label dynamically -->
                     <apex:inputText style="width:80%;" disabled="true" styleClass="setupModel" value="{!asset.Product_Code_for_Paperless_Install_Docs__c}"  />
                </apex:column>
                
                <apex:column style="width:12%;" headerValue="Serial Number Install"><!-- to take the label dynamically -->
                    <apex:inputText style="width:80%;" disabled="" styleClass="installSerialNumber" value="{!asset.New_Asset_Install_LOC_Serial_Number__c}"  />
                </apex:column>
                
                <apex:column style="width:6%; text-align:center;" value="{!asset.Serialized__c}"/>
                
                <apex:column style="width:13%;" headerValue="I Verified the Serial Number"><!-- to take the label dynamically -->
                    <apex:inputCheckbox styleClass="serialDoesntMatchCheckBoxOnAsset" value="{!asset.I_Verify_the_Serial_Number_is_Correct__c}"/>
                </apex:column>
                
                <apex:column style="width:.01%;" headerValue=""><!-- to take the label dynamically -->
                    <apex:inputText style="width:.01%;" disabled="true" id="pbi" styleClass="setupSerialNumber" value="{!asset.Serial_Number_Service_Setup__c}"  />
                </apex:column>
                
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
        
        
        
        <apex:pageBlockTable rows="1" id="pbt2" value="{!Case.Assets__r}" var="asset">
            
                <apex:column style="" headerValue="Location Remarks"><!-- to take the label dynamically -->
                    <apex:inputTextarea styleClass="locationRemarks" style="width:99.45%;" value="{!asset.New_Asset_Install_Equipment_Location__c}"  />
                </apex:column>
                
                <apex:column style="" headerValue="Install Notes"><!-- to take the label dynamically -->
                    <apex:inputTextarea styleClass="installNotes" style="width:99.45%;" value="{!asset.Install_Notes__c}"  />
                </apex:column>
            
                <apex:column headerValue="Customer DocuSign Link" >
                    <apex:outputLink target="_blank" style="width:99.45%;" value="{!case.Customer_DocuSign_Link__c}">
                        Customer DocuSign Link
                    </apex:outputLink>
                </apex:column>
            
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
        
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="pbs2" columns="2">
            <apex:inputField id="cheaterOnSite" onchange="cheaterLeftOnSite(); return false;" value="{!case.Cheater_Left_On_Sight__c}"/>
            <apex:inputCheckbox styleClass="autoSerialCheck" onchange="" id="serialNumberVerified" disabled="" value="{!Case.Serial_Numbers_Verified__c}"/>
            <apex:inputText id="cheaterId" value="{!case.Cheater_ID__c}"/>
            <apex:inputCheckbox onchange="enableUpdateButton(); return false;" id="manualSerialNumberVerification" disabled="" value="{!Case.Manual_Serial_Number_Verification__c}"/>
            <apex:inputCheckbox id="cheaterCheckBox" value="{!case.Cheater_was_used_at_install__c}"/>
            <apex:inputCheckbox id="install" value="{!Case.Install_Complete__c}"/>
            
          
            
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <p class="serialDoesntMatch">
            <apex:inputCheckbox id="serialDoesntMatchCheckBox" value="{!Case.Asset.I_Verify_the_Serial_Number_is_Correct__c}"/> 
            The above serial number(s) have been verified by <strong>{!$User.FirstName} {!$User.LastName}.</strong>
            <br/>
            <strong>{!$User.FirstName} {!$User.LastName}</strong> has uploaded a document that verifies the correct serial number
           
        </p>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">  
             <apex:commandButton styleClass="verify" id="verify" onclick="verifySerialNumbers(); return false;" value="Verify" />
            <apex:commandButton oncomplete="congrats(); return false;" styleClass="update" id="update" disabled="" value="Update" action="{!saveSerialIdNumber}" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

And here is my apex class:

```
public class installTicketUpdateAssetClass {
        private ApexPages.StandardController controller;
    
        //Constructor 
        public installTicketUpdateAssetClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
            this.controller = controller;
        }
    
        public void saveSerialIdNumber() {
            // here we use the standard controller's capability of fetching related records to update them ourselves 
            // (Casting is needed because YourChildRelationshipName__r is specific to your case object)
            update ((Case) controller.getRecord()).Assets__r;
            // here we call the standard controller's "update"
            controller.save();
        }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by updating the save button in my class:

```
public class installTicketUpdateAssetClass {
private ApexPages.StandardController controller;


public installTicketUpdateAssetClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
}
```

public void saveSerialIdNumber() {

```
    for(Asset assetObj : (list<Asset>) ((Case) controller.getRecord()).Assets__r){
        assetObj.SerialNumber = assetObj.New_Asset_Install_LOC_Serial_Number__c;
    }
    update ((Case) controller.getRecord()).Assets__r;
   
    controller.save();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can't point a Visualforce input field at more than one underlying data field. You'll need to either write Apex code to iterate over `Case.Assets__r` before you perform your `update` to assign the value to `SerialNumber`, or build business process automation (Apex trigger, or your declarative tool of choice) to apply this rule globally by populating all updates to `New_Asset_Install_LOC_Serial_Number__c` into `SerialNumber`.